# Cannot connect to ServiceFabricCluster using "Connect-ServiceFabricCluster"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to connect to ServiceFabricCluster using "Connect-ServiceFabricCluster" but keep getting

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details
```

The command I am using is:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $endpoint `
    -X509Credential `
    -ServerCertThumbprint $serverThumbprint `
    -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue $serverThumbprint `
    -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

for the value $serverThumbprint I am using the thumbprint on the Azure portal for the cert in question (see below)

[image]

I have also downloaded the .cer from Azure and installed it on my machine.

For the endpoint, I am using the "Client connection endpoint" supplied in the overview blade of the cluster.

Comment: can you add the error? Is there a firewall between you and the cluster, blocking port 19000?

Answer (score 0):

> I have also downloaded the .cer from Azure and installed it on my
>   machine.

That's the point, instead of **.cer** you had to download **.PFX** containing both private and public key, and then install it to both **Personal** and **Trusted Root** directories of the **Current User**.
Then, in the publish profile of your app you need to specify the following section:

```
<ClusterConnectionParameters
ConnectionEndpoint="XXX.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000"
X509Credential="true"
FindType="FindByThumbprint"
FindValue="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
ServerCertThumbprint="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
StoreLocation="CurrentUser"
StoreName="My" />
```

FindValue and ServerCertThumbprint are the same.